How do I enable i18n in nextjs without invoking the middleware?
My Nextjs14 app-router application uses next-i18next package in order to enable internationalization. This involves using next-i18n-router to handle redirections to the corresponding locale routes:

/ for english page
/fr for french page.

The next-i18n-router has been added in the middleware to intercept every page request and return a response using return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);. But this increases the our Middleware Invocation costs in Vercel since all page requests call the middleware.
Is there a way to enable i18n without the use of middleware? Or is there a way to reduce middleware costs?
